# Linear filtering of floating point textures in WebGL2

Tags: javascript, textures, webgl2

I'm trying to get work Floating point textures in WebGL2. I initialize textures like this:

```
function textureFromFloat32Array( gl, arr, w, h ){
    //https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OES_texture_float_linear
    gl.getExtension('OES_texture_float');        // just in case
    gl.getExtension('OES_texture_float_linear'); // do I need this with WebGL2
    const texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    // see https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/2.0/#TEXTURE_TYPES_FORMATS_FROM_DOM_ELEMENTS_TABLE
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.R32F, w, h, 0, gl.RED, gl.FLOAT, arr);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    //gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST); // this works
    //gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    return texture;
}
```

In Firefox 55.0.2 (64-bit) it gives me following error:

`Error: WebGL warning: drawElements: Active texture 0 for target 0x0de1 is 'incomplete', and will be rendered as RGBA(0,0,0,1), as per the GLES 2.0.24 $3.8.2: Because minification or magnification filtering is not NEAREST or NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST, and the texture's format must be "texture-filterable".`

With `gl.NEAREST` it works but I need linear interpolation.

In Chorme 60.0.3112.101 it works with  `gl.getExtension('OES_texture_float_linear');` but I guess when using `WebGL2` I should not need it.

Answer (score 5):

Even WebGL2 requires `OES_texture_float_linear`.

WebGL2 supports floating point textures by default but it does not support filtering them or rendering to them by default. Both of those are extensions. See the [tables on this page](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-data-textures.html) for which texture formats are supported and whether or not you can filter them or render to them.

Most mobile phones do not support filtering floating point textures nor do they support rendering to floating point textures. At least as of September 2017.

To be able to filter floating point textures you need to check for and enable `OES_texture_float_linear`. To be able to render to floating point textures you need to check for and enable `EXT_color_buffer_float`

Comment: thanks, good to know. But what it actually mean "not renderable" ... what I can do with that texture then? Does it mean I can use it only in vertex shader not in pixelshader? I actually want to use it for 3 things? 1) as terrainheight map 2) for raymarching of 3D texture 3) as a buffers for calcualtions (using transform feedback or compute shaders).

Comment: not renderable means you can not render do it. In other words you can not attach it a framebuffer. not filterable means you can not filter indirectly through the sampler. Meaning the sampler must be set to `NEAREST`. Having a float texture is still super useful even if you can't filter it. A good example is skinning matrices are often stored in textures since you need more than will fit in uniforms. They don't need to be filtered. You can also filter manually in your shader (read the texture multiple times, sum and average result). Of course it will likely be slow.

Comment: So, you can use it as a heightmap. It will just have to set to nearest. That's not usually a problem for a heightmap. It seems like you could use it to raymarch except of course it might be grainy unless you do your own filtering. You might consider the 16bit float formats for that as they can be filtered by default. As for buffers for calculations, you can use them as input but not as output unless the device supports `EXT_color_buffer_float`. most desktops do. most phones/tablets do not.

Comment: And with extension "OES_texture_float_linear" it should work also in firefox (maybe I just do it wrong, in wrong combination of paprameters?). Because I learned about that extension form mozzila webpages().

The thing is, I already have several program using linear inteprolation of floating point textures in python+OpenCL and C++/OpenGL and whould like to use it with minima changes in shaders. Also they are performance critical so hardware interpolations is relly helpful.